# replace some characters to space with escaped character

Tags: java, jsp

I have send whitespace from jsp to java with [P] character, and in java i want to convert [P] to whitespace but with escaped character like (\n,\t), so im using

```
replace("[P]", "\\s");
```

but when insert to database, the whitespace become \s, for example Dear\sCustomer\sPlease\sRegister

Comment: i don't understand, post sample input and desired output. :) Also `\n` and `\t` aren't regex, they are just escaped characters.

Comment: oh sorry then, escaped characters, i will edit the question

Comment: so actually in my java, i have 1 line code like this :
`reqLtrContent = reqLtrContent.replace("[X]", "\n").replace("[Y]", "\t").replace("[P]", "\\s");` it works for \n and \t, and converted to new line and tab to database

Comment: i answered it for you below. You have to escape the backslash as well to escape the square brackets. And use `" "` for white space.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to do 
`str.replace("[P]", " ")  //single blank space`

'\s' is just an escape character and the behaviour which you are experiencing is expected behavior and how replace was designed to work

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: REFRESH your page mate

Answer (score 0):

**CODE**

```
    String abc = "asdjasodjad[P]dsklfjsfljslkfd[P]dfsfds";
    String def = abc.replaceAll("\\[P\\]", " ");
    System.out.println(def);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
asdjasodjad dsklfjsfljslkfd
```

that would replace all [P] with white space. You have to escape the backslash to escape the square brackets!

**EDIT** BTW Beginner, the \s is only for regular expressions and not for escape characters.